# to Swap elemnts(with className too) when Draged & Dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Swapping two elements whenever one element dragged and dropped over another element. I used [Vadim's JQuery plugin](http://www.eslinstructor.net/demo/swappable/swappable_grid.html) and it's working but i have an issue with height,Width,position & float of swapped elements.***

*Swapped elements doesn't fit if the className & it's attributes were different. Should i swap the className too  OR just swap only certain attributes.*

*** [for better understanding please check my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bibhaw/vtBVR/47/)***

Comment: @Felix Kling my Question is : how to fix the width,height,float & position of swapped elements whether i'm not sure how to swap these attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example elements behave exactly as they should behave based on the css rules you apply to them. You can add or remove classes or recalculate height/width with javascript on stop event:

```
$("#foo").swappable({
    ...
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        alert("drug: "+ ui.item[0].id + ", drop: "+ event.originalEvent.target.id); 
    }
    ...

});
```

Comment: @Vadmik I only want to know which function stores the Object's ID in your plugin JS                                                                                             
      if (dragElement.ID != TargetElement.ID)
                  {
                 var current_ID = dragElement.ID;
                 dargElement.ID = TargetElement.ID;
                 TargetElement.ID = current_ID;
           OR can use toggle}                             
}

Comment: I've edited my answer above. Please take a look at the alert() function.

Answer (score 1):

usally the iu items have methods that can be passed in the initilice object
in your case you can use stop
stop is invoked each time ends swap

example:

$(function() {

```
 $('.row,.column').swappable({
        items:'.class_1,.class_2',
        cursorAt: {top:-20},
      stop: function(event, ui) { alert("hi") }
          });
 $( '.class_1,.class_2' ).addClass( "ui-widget" );
```

});

instead of alert just add or remove the class you need, probably you can use toogle method

tell me if this is what you are looking for 8)

Comment: Hey thanks for your time & help. instead of alert i want to compare dragElement_class and TargetElement_Class, if classes are not same then i want to swap the class inculding with Elements, but not able to fetch the drag_ID & target_id.